Need help, can't figure out why list returned is empty
I am trying spring boot 3.2 jdbc client. I have simple DAO that queries orders and returns list of orders. JDBC returns records but orders list returned from DAO to service class is empty/null
public class OrderDAO {

    private final JdbcClient jdbcClient;

    public OrderDAO(JdbcClient jdbcClient) {
        this.jdbcClient = jdbcClient;
    }
    public List<Order> getOrders(String today) {
        List<Order> orders = null;
        String query = "SELECT order_id,user_id,order_date FROM order WHERE order_date = ? ";
        orders = jdbcClient.sql(query)
        .param(1,today)
        .query(Order.class)
        .list();

        //orders list is not empty here, got orders from db
        System.out.println("Orders returned:" + orders.size());
        return orders;
    }
}

//Service class 

public class OrdersService {

    private final OrderDAO orderDAO;

    public OrdersService(OrderDAO orderDAO){
        this.orderDAO = orderDAO;
    }
    public void processOrders() {
        String today = Utils.getToday();

        //orders list returned here is empty
        List<Order> orders = orderDAO.getOrders(today);

        if(null == orders || orders.isEmpty()) {
            throw new OrderNotFoundException(NO_ORDERS_FOUND.getDescription());
        }
    }
}


What data is in your table? You're using = in your SQL query and if it has a time on it you won't match exactly. What data type is that field and what are the values in it.

Field is just a string (varchar) e.g. 2024-05-01, I am getting data back from DB but list returned from DAO method some how is empty
